# Informix SQL Compare DateTime value on Where Statement

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

I have a datetime field called `entrytimestamp`, with content of the field is for example: `2014-01-07 16:20:00`. I would like to query all the data that has `entrytimestamp` after `09:00:00` o'clock, regardless what date it was.

I have a prototype query:

```
select *
from trading
where to_char(entrytimestamp, "%H%M%S") >= "090000"
```

But I think it is logically a mistake, because it will compare the text string, not the sequence value. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [EXTEND()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqltmst88.htm) function to extract the time part:

```
select *
from mytable
where extend(entrytimestamp, hour to second) > '09:00:00'
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed to compare using time sequence, not alphabetically?

Comment: Makes no difference: Time and alphabetic sorting are identical when time is formatted with leading zeroes in the fields

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it performs well,
but you could compare directly with the time portion of the datetime,

i think a cast here should perform pretty fast (just cuts off the date)

```
select *

from (select getdate() as mydatetime) as data

where cast(mydatetime as time) > cast('09:00:00' as time)
```

EDIT, just noticed this was for Informix SQL, so not sure it works then, Sorry